# Magento Community 1.9.1 how do I add Static Blocks to a sidebar in RWD?

Tags: magento-community, static-block, rwd-theme, sidebar

The last theme I used had identifiers in the theme for placing CMS blocks into theme pages. Does RWD have existing layout identifiers I can use? or do I have to add code to my layout.xml? RWD's right sidebar is a bit empty looking. Also, I see the paypal sticker on the rightside bar, is this hardwired? I can't find it in the backend.

tia
August

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't exactly what you have asked for but I use free **[Amasty's Easy Content Blocks](https://amasty.com/easy-content-blocks.html)** extension which is quite handy when you want to put static blocks everywhere including sidebars.

Comment: that looks promising. I'll try it, thankyou

Comment: I tried it. It broke my main nav bar and I don't have the time to debug it.

Answer (score 1):

the way I did it is by using a widget, first you create the static block and after you go to widgets, create a new instance and when you configure it, you tell it to use the static block, the pages to apear and you can chose wher it will show up.
Hope this helps